# Tengo una duda si hay otra forma de unir tres archivos con un solo ID

Tags: c#

Tengo este código que es para guardar un nombre de app, usuario y contraseña y tengo tres archivos con los mismos nombres, cada uno se guarda en un archivo distinto por eso tres y mi pregunta es si se podía hacer de otra forma para unir los tres archivos con un mismo ID por que no me termina de convencer hacerlo de esta forma. se que es mejor hacerlo todo en un solo archivo o encriptar los datos pero solo es un ejercicio.

Intenté hacer otro método pero me da bastantes errores.

```
namespace trabajo_integrador
{

    public partial class fromalta : Form


    {
         public fromalta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool K = false;
            if(textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                label5.Visible = true;
                K = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label5.Visible = false;
            }
            if(textBox2.Text == "" && K == false)
            {
                label6.Visible = true;
                K = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label6.Visible = false;
            }
         
            if (textBox3.Text == "" && K == false)
            {
                label7.Visible = true;
                K = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label7.Visible = false;
            }

            if (textBox3.Text != textBox4.Text && K == false)
            {
                label8.Visible = true;
                K = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label8.Visible = false;
            }

            if(K == false)
            {
                FileStream User = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/altausuario.txt", FileMode.Open);
                FileStream Pass = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/altacontraseña.txt", FileMode.Open);
                FileStream App = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/altaaplicacion.txt", FileMode.Open);

                StreamReader leerUser = new StreamReader(User);
                StreamReader leerPass = new StreamReader(Pass);
                StreamReader leerApp = new StreamReader(App);
                StreamWriter escribirUser = new StreamWriter(User);
                StreamWriter escribirPass = new StreamWriter(Pass);
                StreamWriter escribirApp = new StreamWriter(App);
                
                String auxiapli;
                String auxiusuario;
                String auxicontra;

                String[] auxiVector = new String[0];
                int A = 0;

                while (leerUser.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    auxiusuario = leerUser.ReadLine();
                    auxiVector = auxiusuario.Split(';');
                    A = Convert.ToInt32(auxiVector[0]);
                }
                while (leerPass.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    auxicontra = leerPass.ReadLine();
                    auxiVector = auxicontra.Split(';');
                    A = Convert.ToInt32(auxiVector[0]);
                }

                while (leerApp.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    auxiapli = leerApp.ReadLine();
                    auxiVector = auxiapli.Split(';');
                    A = Convert.ToInt32(auxiVector[0]);
                }
                auxiapli = textBox1.Text;
                auxiusuario = textBox2.Text;
                auxicontra = textBox3.Text;
                A++;
                escribirUser.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(A) + ";" + auxiusuario);
                escribirPass.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(A) + ";" + auxicontra);
                escribirApp.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(A) + ";" + auxiapli);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes 1 separar en el encriptado por alguna frase o espacio y cuando leas el archivo (*framento1-/delimitador/-fragmento2-/delimitador/-fragmento3*) único archivo.

Lo otro que puede hacer es una carpeta con código único y todos los archivos corresponde al id `"fecha"+"identificador"` o cada archivo por el mimo número pero con fechas distintas y uses un delimitador de fechas `/fecha+hora/-/identidad/`.